# Можно ли работать с mongodb напрямую из браузера, без использования node.js?

Tags: node.js, json, javascript, nosql

Можно ли работать с mongodb напрямую из браузера, без использования node.js?

Comment: Да и вообще - какой смысл? Если юзать БД все-равно нужен сервер , соответственно не вижу абсолютно никакого смысла в такого рода извращениях

Comment: Спасибо. Я так и думал.
Такой вопрос возник после манипуляций с эмулятором командной строки на офсайте mongodb.

Comment: для mongo есть REST-API, которым можно постить, удалять, модифицировать и извлекать данные, в том числе и из js напрямую. Вот облачный сервис [MongoLab][1], здесь [Описание API][2] для него...

[1]:https://mongolab.com/home
[2]:http://support.mongolab.com/entries/20433053-rest-api-for-mongodb

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку. Очень интересно.

Comment: @AlexWindHope, посмотрите на Apache CouchDB, может увидите смысл

Comment: Когда я писал нельзя - я имел введу абсолютную безсмысленность. Какая это, к черту, БД если любой знающий JS человек с консоли может натворить делов?

Единственное где я вижу этому применение - это админка или что-то в таком духе (и то, далеко не всегда), не более. Возможно я не прав, но это вряд-ли.

Comment: @AlexWindHope, а в традиционной БД через, скажем, sqlplus тоже можно натворить делов ?

Comment: Когда используется SQL*Plus то это, по сути, мало отличается от запросов к БД через язык программирования. Соответственно мне не совсем понятно - причем здесь это?

Да, в mongo rest api есть аутентификация и т.д. Но если пользователь аутентифицирован - он попросту может просмотреть все данные (в т.ч., естественно, например пароли и т.д.) и сделать с ними все что пожелает.

Да, эта проблема решается серверным кодом, но, собственно возникает вопрос - а зачем тогда вообще нужен этото REST API?

Comment: Добавлю - если использовать права пользователей то это **частично** решает проблему необходимости использования сервера, но для общих данных (например выборка из коллекций пользователей) все-равно нужно писать **СЕРВЕРНЫЙ КОД**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, какой смысл тогда в БД? Что от нее остается, кроме как большего хранилища данных, которое может почистить либо слить любой, кому не лень? Во-вторых, mongodb - это база данных и она никак не требует использовать на сервере именно node.js (хотя с нодой ИМХО - "сексуальнее" всего).

Несмотря на то, что такого делать нельзя, вы можете ооочень просто написать клиентский API для возможности выполнения любых запросов, но имейте ввиду, их так же сможет выполнить любой пользователь, знающий JavaScript.

Comment: Область применения у такого решения есть. Расшаривание данных для одного юзера с разных девайсов. Каждый пользователь работает со своими данными и только. На компе авторизовался, занес данные, они доступны этому же пользователю по той же авторизации на его телефоне или планшете.

Учитывая то, что сейчас модно писать на html5 кроссдевайсные приложения, толстые клиенты, им не хватает только данных в облаке.

В маркете довольно часто вижу в комментариях к приложениям типа списка покупок просьбу сделать сохранение в облаке...

Comment: Пример. Написал gps регистратор для жены своей, залил ей на телефон, смотрю куда она ездила :)

Comment: не понял сути - для описанных вами вещей вовсе *не обязательно* использовать такой подход, если в чем-то не прав - поправьте пожалуйста

Comment: В данном случае серверной логики нет. Вся логика пишется на клиенте, нужно именно хранилище данных, внешнее. При этом никакого несанкционированного доступа к данным нет, пользователь один, работает только со своими данными.
Не знаю как еще точнее донести мысль.